# Run-time error '424 object required

Tags: excel, string, vba, loops

I am trying to create loop that will go through each year of stock data and grab the total amount of volume each stock had over the year from an file with three sheets. Each sheet is a different year.

First i created the following code

```
Sub WorksheetLoop2()

 ' Declare Current as a worksheet object variable.
 Dim Current As Worksheet

 ' Loop through all of the worksheets in the active workbook.
  For Each Current In Worksheets
       ' Insert your code here.
       ' This line displays the worksheet name in a message box.
       MsgBox Current.Name
    Next
 End Sub
```

The code ran a message box with all three years

Since i want to create a script that will loop through each year of stock data and grab the total amount of volume each stock had over the year the following code was created:

```
Sub WorksheetLoop2()
  ' Declare Current as a worksheet object variable.
    Dim Current As Worksheet

    ' Loop through all of the worksheets in the active workbook.
    For Each Current In Worksheets

    Dim varRowCount As Integer
    'varRowCount = 0
    Dim key As Variant
    Dim TotalVolume As Double
    Dim lastrow As Integer

    Dim i As Single
    Dim tickers As Object                 'scripting.dictionery
    Set tickers = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")  'make dictinery object

    Current.Activate
       'Current.Select           
       ' Insert your code here.
       ' This line displays the worksheet name in a message box.
       'MsgBox Current.Name

    lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

       For i = 2 To lastrow
       key = Current.Rows(i).Cells(2, 1)

       If Not tickers.exists(key) Then
           ' The Key does not exists we need to add to the dictionary collection
           TotalVolume = Current.Rows(i).Cells(2, 7)
           tickers.Add key, TotalVolume
       Else
         ' Key exist so we need update previous value
         TotalVolume = tickers(key) ' First get the value
         ' Update the values
         TotalVolume = TotalVolume + Current.Rows(i).Cells(2, 7)
         ' Finally update the collection value
         tickers.Item(key) = TotalVolume
       End If
       'MsgBox (Current.Rows(i).Cells(2, 1))

       Next i           
    Next

    'MsgBox (tickers.Item("A"))

    'For Each key In tickers.Keys
     'MsgBox ("Ticker:" & key & " TotalVolume:" & tickers(key))
    'Next key
    MsgBox (tickers("A"))
 End Sub
```

however, I keep getting the error

> Run-time error '424 object required

When I try to debug it, I get the following highlighted `lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: I think you meant to use `Current` instead of `ws`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fully qualify your `Rows` reference like this:

```
lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

Otherwise it uses `ActiveSheet`

Comment: Your point is valid, but I don't think `ws` is what OP intended to use: `For each Current in Worksheets`...